# Highlight Author in git log

Tags: git

How might one configure Git to highlight the Author for each commit in `git log`? Ideally, only the Author's name would be highlighted (red font), but if the only option is to highlight the entire line then that would work as well.

I notice that the `commit` line is highlighted with an orange font, which is why I suspect that this is possible to configure. However, I cannot find in the configuration files this option, nor could I find it with a google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a pretty format git log command. This is roughly a plain `git log` with the author in red.

```
git log --pretty=format:"commit %C(yellow)%H%Creset%nAuthor: %Cred%an%Creset <%ae>%nDate: %ad%n%n%B%n"
```

The important bits are the `%C(yellow)%H%Creset` which is the commit highlight, and `%Cred%an%Cresest` which is author's name in red.

Comment: Thank you. However, this removes the highlight on the `commit` line! Where is this documented, so that I might adjust it as I see fit?

Comment: Do git help log and all the format commands are there.  The commit line isn't highlighted on my system

Comment: I've added the commit highlight, "orange" is actually yellow though it looks orange to me too

Comment: I am actually having a hard time massaging this to properly display multi-line comments. Right now they all appear on the same line. Do you have any idea what might be causing the issue? Thank you!

Comment: What format statement are you using?  %n is the new line.

Comment: I actually mean the text of the comment itself. When I comment I'll open VIM and have a few line: `Fixed foo()`, `Broke bar()`. Each will appear on a separate line when I do `git log` but will be on the same line if I use the line that you mentioned.

Comment: I've done some research and it seems to be a feature of git which is annoying when the default command does show multiple lines.

Comment: Scrap that, try %B instead of %s

Comment: Thanks, parkydr! That works! I have edited the post but had to put some filler at the bottom.